# Replace/Remove "]" sign in logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I'm trying to convert a text type field into a float one in Logstash and ElasticSearch mapping.
The field name is votingPercentage.
My log looks as follow: "votingPercentage = 0.13]" 
Since there's a "]" sign in the end of the field's value - the ElasticSearch cannot map it into float.
In order to delete the "]" sign, I've tried to do the following configuration in logstash.conf file:

```
mutate {
gsub => [
"votingPercentage", "[]g]", " "
]
}
```

(using g as global)
This configuration has dropped the "]" sign and enabled the votingPercentage field to be mapped as float, but it has also dropped any appearance of the "g" letter in the field, so the result is: "votin Percenta e" is now the field name.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use grok to grab just the percentage, with a filter like this:

```
  grok {
      match => {
      "message" => 'votingPercentage = %{NUMBER:votingPercentage}]'
      }
  }
```

Also, I don't think you need to put a global flag, since by default the gsub filter will replace all the occurrences and even so, you only have one `]` (as far as I can see).

Comment: Thanks, but it did not solve the problem as we got "number_format_exception".
However, in order to workaround this issue we add a blank space before the "]" and that helped us to solve this issue:

mutate {
    gsub => [
      "msg", "]", " ]"
]
}

Comment: @ShayKatz if you want my help on solving the number_format_exception, could you add the configuration and the line causing the error to your question, please? I don't understand where the error is coming from with what I know. But if you are satisfied with your workaround, I understand if you don't want to spend more time on that.